# Dusk to dawn wiring for 2 lights

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

How can I wire 2 dusk-to-dawn lights on one circuit so they work independently of each other?

Comment: What make and model are these lights?

Answer (score 2):

Wiring the hot black wire and neutral white to each light will allow there sensors to control the lights for each fixture. Make sure the sensors are not pointed in the direction of the other light or there may be enough light from 1 fixture to turn the 2nd fixture off.